# como puedo descomponer un diccionario con sublistas Python

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

estoy intentando descomponer un diccionario que contiene sublistas,
Por ejemplo:

dict_aux_idds = {

'idd': [],

}

dict_aux_idds['idd'] = [[''], ['215'], ['219,320,352,361'], ['225'], ['220'], ['235'], ['250'], ['242'], ['319']]

Como puedo obtener cada sublista pero convirtiendola a otra lista simple?

Resultado:

['219,320,352,361'] ----> [219, 320, 352, 361] , len = 4

['215']   ---->  [215]   , len = 1

Alguien me puede echar una ayuda por favor?

Comment: Probablemente [str.split](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) te sirva. Es más, el ejemplo en la documentación coincide con tu caso.

Comment: Por cierto, cuando hagas una pregunta aquí, es importante demostrar que eres parte del esfuerzo por responder tu propia duda, sea mostrando lo que has intentado con un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) y/o una lista de algunos de los links que visitaste buscando la solución. Preguntas sin eso no suelen ser bien recibidas. Por favor lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @DanteS. De acuerdo gracias, no coloque ningun ejemplo porque era basicamente lo mismo que salia en la descripcion, si logro encontrar la solucion de todas maneras me auto respondo mi pregunta. Gracias por ayudar.

Comment: De nada Matias c:

Comment: @DanteS. No me sirvio de mucho el str.split() amigo...

Comment: Por que? Recuerda que debes hacer otras cosas antes de usar split. Si editas tu pregunta y agregas alguno de tus intentos usando str.split es posible que te dé una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict_aux_idds = {
    'idd': [],
}

dict_aux_idds['idd'] = [[''], ['215'], ['219,320,352,361'], ['225'], ['220'], ['235'], ['250'], ['242'], ['319']]

def separar(s):
    #Si la string está vacía, retornamos una lista vacía
    #Esto es necesario porque split(',') no retorna una lista vacía
    if s[0] == '':
        return []
    #Si no está vacía, separamos la lista usando split y converimos cada string a int usando map
    return list(map(lambda n: int(n), s[0].split(',')))

#Aplicamos la función separar a cada elemento de dict_aux_idds['idd'] usando map
dict_aux_idds['idd'] = list(map(separar, dict_aux_idds['idd']))

print(dict_aux_idds['idd'])
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias !